# set default wifi network

Tags: 11.10, networking, network-manager

How do I change the default wifi network that Ubuntu connects to on startup? There is an unsecured public wifi network in my range, as well as my own home WPA secured wifi that I want to use by default. However, on startup Ubuntu always connects to the unsecured one. Sometimes I forget to reconnect to the other one, which is very dangerous.

I am running a default setup of Ubuntu Destkop 11.10 with Gnome 3. I have looked under network settings but I can't find a 'default' option.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Jeroen,

You could try this:

1. Open nm-connection-editor by your terminal;
2. Select the wireless tab;
3. Select the unsecure network, than Edit...
4. Uncheck the option: Connect automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In the future Network Manager will have a priority setting --- it has been a [long 
battle](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/366780), but [it's finally here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=580018).

Now, I have no idea on how long it will take to percolate down and to the user interface. For the time being, your best bet is going into the wireless manager and "forget" or "delete" the connection of your neighbors.

This shot is from Xubuntu, but you'll find a similar one in any Ubuntu flavor:

[image: Network options in Xubuntu]